# localhost:8000 resolves to localhost and "this site can't be reached" but localhost:8000/services works

Tags: wordpress, docker, localhost, docker-compose

When I enter `localhost:8000` in my Chrome browser, it redirects to `localhost` and gives me the ol' "This site can’t be reached - localhost refused to connect."

Going to `localhost:8000/wp-admin` and `localhost:8000/services` both work fine.

I am using [Docker-Wordpress-Compose](https://github.com/brainbytes/docker-compose-wordpress).

Here is my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Here is what I get when I `ping localhost`

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.013 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
```

And when I `ping localhost:8000`

```
ping: cannot resolve localhost:8000: Unknown host
```

Comment: You cannot ping on a port. Maybe you want to try `telnet localhost 8000` to check if something is listening.

Comment: @Sebastian - that returned this: `Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.`

Comment: Then it is working fine. The issue is with some configuration in your app not related to docker.

Answer (score 0):

First do a netstat -pluton to show your open ports, if you don't see your 8000 port maybe it's because you didn't open it with `run -d --link database:database -p 8000:8080 wordpress`, did you try with `localhost:8000/wordpress` ? And check in your apache2.conf if you're allowed to connect.